# SQL query multiplying SUM result by amount of inner elements

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a query that lists features, based on components status and availability

```
SELECT Brand.Id
  , Brand.Name
  , Brand.Impact
  , Brand.Visibility
  , Brand.Risk
  , SUM(Brand.Impact + Brand.Visibility + Brand.Risk) AS Priority

FROM Brand 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Type 
  ON Brand.Id = Type.FeatureId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Model 
  ON Type.Id = Model.SubFeatureId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TestingStatus 
  ON Model.StatusId = TestingStatus.Id

WHERE (Model.IsDeleted = 'False') 
  AND (Brand.IsDeleted = 'False') 
  AND (Type.IsDeleted = 'False')
  AND (@TeamId = 0 OR Model.TeamId = @TeamId)
GROUP BY Brand.YearId, Brand.Id, Brand.Name, Brand.Impact, Brand.Visibility, Brand.Risk
HAVING (Brand.YearId = @YearId)
```

My results are as follow:

```
ID  Name    Impact  Visibility  Risk    Priority
403 Chevy   1       2           3       48
404 Nissan  1       1           1       24
405 Toyota  3       2           1       42
```

Instead of

```
ID  Name    Impact  Visibility  Risk    Priority
403 Chevy   1       2           3       6
404 Nissan  1       1           1       3
405 Toyota  3       2           1       6
```

Each of these brands have respectively 8, 8 and 7 models. Which means that my query is doing for all of them to calculate priority: `Impact*models + Visibility*models + Risk*models`.

How can I get my SQL query to not do that multiplication?

Thanks

Comment: is your priority just supposed to be the total of the impact, visibility and risk?

Comment: Yes @bluefeet that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment and unless I am not understanding what you need, I don't think you need the `SUM()`.  I think you just want the total for each model.  Using the `SUM()` you are going to get the total for all records which it doesn't sound like you want. This would also remove your `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT Brand.Id
  , Brand.Name
  , Brand.Impact
  , Brand.Visibility
  , Brand.Risk
  , (Brand.Impact + Brand.Visibility + Brand.Risk) AS Priority

FROM Brand 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Type 
  ON Brand.Id = Type.FeatureId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Model 
  ON Type.Id = Model.SubFeatureId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN TestingStatus 
  ON Model.StatusId = TestingStatus.Id

WHERE (Model.IsDeleted = 'False') 
  AND (Brand.IsDeleted = 'False') 
  AND (Type.IsDeleted = 'False')
  AND (@TeamId = 0 OR Model.TeamId = @TeamId)
  AND (Brand.YearId = @YearId)
```

Comment: Ok now I just feel stupid for not trying that... ^^ Thank you!

Comment: @LanFeusT we all do it now and again. sometimes it takes an extra pair of eyes. :)